# app.config in a Class Library - asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, class-library

I have a class library application and am unable to configure a CONFIG file. My app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="test" value="value test"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

and the call in my application:

```
var test = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["test"];
```

But when I run, always passes a null value.

Comment: How are you running a class library?

Comment: I call my class library through a web project. I managed to set the webconfig of Web project. It was something simple that I was complicating. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Class libraries do not use a .config file.  Only applications (app.config) and web site s(web.config) read the "config" file.

The class library can use the Configuration Manager to read a value, but they must running inside of an app/web site.

In ASP.Net rename 'app.config' to 'web.config' and place it in the root folder of web site.

Comment: off-topic: Why did you approve this [obvious spam edit to a tag](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3859274)? Can you please pay attention when reviewing suggested edits?

Comment: I call my class library through a web project. I managed to set the webconfig of Web project. It was something simple that I was complicating. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the `appSettings` tag in the web.config of your website in order to use `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["test"]` if you do not want to do that then make the setting `xml` file and read it in your *library* code.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to the web.confg

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="test" value="value test"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And this is get value

```
var test = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["test"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing string you may use
in webconfig

```
  <appSettings>
  <add key="test" value="value test"/>
  </appSettings>
```

In cs.

```
  String update = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["test "]);
```

Answer (score 0):

thank u all!

I used my config from my web application and solved the problem. It was something simple that I was complicating.